# How to make savefig use less memory with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to generate line charts. The data is quite big, like 600000 points.

When saving it to PNG file with `fig.savefig('out.pdf', transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)` lot of RAM is used, something like 2GB. This could be a problem.
Is it possible to reduce memory used during savefig? Or is it possible to add lines/curves after saving to the file?

Comment: Do you really need all 600000 points as vector graphics? 

One option is to save the lines as raster images and the axes and text as vector graphics (e.g. by setting `rasterized=True` in your `plt.plot()` commands.

Comment: Yes, I really need all the points. Thenk you for the answer but rasterized=True didn't help much.